# Bold text in ListView item

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to set a ListView item or a specific column in the ListView into bold. Here is my code, I know its not right so I am asking for help in order to make it work.

```
Do While reader.Read = True
    list = ListView1.Items.Add(reader(3).ToString)
    list.SubItems.Add(reader(4).ToString = Font.Bold)
    list.SubItems.Add(reader(5).ToString)
    list.SubItems.Add(reader(6).ToString)
Loop
```

Comment: You set the font style for a `ListViewItem` or a `ListViewSubItem` in pretty much exactly the same way as you do for a `TextBox`, i.e. you create a `Font` with the appropriate style set and assign that to the `Font` property. It will be easy to find examples on how to do that for a `TextBox` and that's basically all you need.  If you're doing this for subitems then there's one more thing to be aware of, but you can find that out by reading the documentation for the `Font` property, which I'm sure that you would have done anyway.

Comment: By the way, if you're displaying data from a database in tabular format then you should mot be using a `ListView` at all.  It is NOT a grid control.  That's what the `DataGridView` is for, in which case you can simply populate a `DataTable` and bind.  If you're not using groups or multiple views in a `ListView` then you shouldn't be using it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Font first then associate that Font to the ListViewItem and/or ListViewSubItem

```
    Dim fnt_Font As Font
    Dim lvitm_Item As ListViewItem


    ' Set Font
    fnt_Font = New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

    Do While reader.Read = True

        ' Add ListView Item
        lvitm_Item = ListView1.Items.Add(reader(3).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvitm_Item.Font = fnt_Font

        ' Add SubItem
        lvitm_Item.SubItems.Add(reader(4).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvitm_Item.SubItems(1).Font = fnt_Font

        ' Add SubItem
        lvitm_Item.SubItems.Add(reader(5).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvitm_Item.SubItems(2).Font = fnt_Font

        ' Add SubItem
        lvitm_Item.SubItems.Add(reader(6).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvitm_Item.SubItems(3).Font = fnt_Font

    Loop

    ' Clean Objects
    lvitm_Item = Nothing
```

OR

```
    Dim fnt_Font As Font
    Dim lvitm_Item As ListViewItem
    Dim lvsbitm_SubItem as ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem


    ' Set Font
    fnt_Font = New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

    Do While reader.Read = True

        ' Add ListView Item
        lvitm_Item = ListView1.Items.Add(reader(3).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvitm_Item.Font = fnt_Font

        ' Add SubItem
        lvsbitm_SubItem = lvitm_Item.SubItems.Add(reader(4).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvsbitm_SubItem.Font = fnt_Font

        ' Add SubItem
        lvsbitm_SubItem = lvitm_Item.SubItems.Add(reader(5).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvsbitm_SubItem.Font = fnt_Font

        ' Add SubItem
        lvsbitm_SubItem = lvitm_Item.SubItems.Add(reader(6).ToString)

        ' Add Font
        lvsbitm_SubItem.Font = fnt_Font

    Loop

    ' Clean Objects
    lvsbitm_SubItem = Nothing
    lvitm_Item = Nothing
```

You can add a different Font for each ListViewItem and ListViewSubItem.

Depending on your needs a DataGridView would be better suited for Table like control.

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can assign bold by making a new bold front from your existing listview item font as follows:

```
lvw_item.Font = New Font(lvw_item.Font, FontStyle Bold)
```

To change the subitem fonts individually, you have to set this value:

```
lvw_item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
```

Then you can set the subitem fonts individually:

```
lvw_itm.SubItem(1).Font = New Font(lvw_item.SubItem(1).Font, FontStyle Bold)
```